# New Reference Variable Each Time I create an Object?

Tags: java, oop, object

Lets say I have a Car Class and I create a reference variable for this Car Class.

`Car car = new Car()`- Fairly Straightforward.

I edit the properties of that car by calling: `car.setColor("Red"), and car.setPrice(2500).`

Now, let's say I want to create a new Car Object, do I have to create a new reference variable like this: `Car car2= new Car();` or can I just simply use the original reference variable for the new car?

Comment: What do you want? What did you mean by creating a new reference variable? Do you want to have the data from the old object? Do you want them to point to the same actual object?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** It's up to you.

Long answer: You can use either method. If you create a new car, the previous car that you created will not be affected, because different objects are completely independent. Let's say

```
Car car1 = new Car();
car1.setColor("Red");
car1.setPrice(2500);
Car car2 = new Car();
car2.setColor("Blue");
car2.setPrice(3000);
```

Now `car1` and `car2` have different colours and prices. If you change the values of `car1`, `car2` will not be affected.

Alternatively, you reuse `car1`:

```
Car car1 = new Car();
car1.setColor("Red");
car1.setPrice(2500);
car1 = new Car(); //You created the new car here
car1.setColor("Blue");
car1.setPrice(3000);
```

After this code, the original content of `car1` is lost<sup>*</sup>. This can be used if you think `car1` is not useful anymore and its contents can be discarded.

<sup>*</sup><sub>Note: the object of `car1` is still in memory. But it is inaccessible.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Sweeper's answer:

If we instead do this:

```
Car car1 = new Car();
car1.setColor("Red");
car1.setPrice(2500);
Car car2 = car1;
car2.setColor("Blue");
car2.setPrice(3000);
```

Then both car1 and car2 will have a color of blue and a price of 3000, because they are pointed at the same object. If we then reassign car1:

```
car1 = new Car();
car1.setColor("Green");
car1.setPrice(0);
```

car1 would have a color of green and a price of 0, but car2 would still have a color of blue and a price of 3000, because it is still referencing the original object created for car1.

Answer (score 0):

Object is nothing but the temporary buffer created in the Heap.

Whenever you create a new object, a new buffer(or space) is provided in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly reuse your first `car` variable, and this is common in some cases (such as loops). Keep in mind that the original variable's reference will be replaced, so unless you've stored a reference to the object somewhere else (such as in a collection or a field on another object), the object will be garbage collected.